# how to upload current date in mongoose schema when saving it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

I want to update the current date in yyy-mm-dd form so i can query it later but i m unable to insert date in the required format.here what i had did till

```
 const sampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username:String,
    date:{
    type:Date
  }
});

const Sample = new mongoose.model("Sample", sampleSchema);


let currentDate=new Date
 
  const sample = new  Sample({
    username:req.body.username,
    date:currentDate.toISOString().split("T")[0]
  });
  sample.save()
```

I'm getting this

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61b5862c6ff7ff297ae97d0c"
    },
    "user": "username",
    "date": {
        "$date": "2021-12-12T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

I want date in yyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: it is standard ISO format, and mongodb only store date in ISO format, for your customize format you can change your field type from Date to String and store your desire format.

Comment: how can i query it within two range with mongoose?

Comment: using `$gt`, `$gte`, `$lte` and `$lt` operators.

Answer (score 1):

Use moment.js to convert the ISO formatted date into normal formatted date YYYY-MM-DD Don't try to store your own formate of date on MongoDB because it creates problems in querying data based on date and time. So update it into ISO and then convert it into different formate at the backend

Converting ISO formate Date into YYYY MM DD

```
date = new Date('2013-08-03T02:00:00Z');

date = moment(date).format('YYYY MM DD'); //result 2013 08 03
```

Converting YYYY MM DD formate into IOS formate

```
date = new Date('2013-08-03');
date = moment(date).format();
```

Another thing users can do is to store data in the form of a string
and use $gt, $gte, $lte and $lt operators for queries